# How do I put a class instance at north of border layout?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, border-layout

I wrote a simple Timer class, and I want to set the frame layout to Border layout and put timer at north. I'm new to layouts, can anyone help me with how to do this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TimerTest extends JFrame{
    JButton timerLabel = null;
    public TimerTest()
    {
        this.setTitle("Timer Test");
        Container c = this.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        timerLabel = new JButton("0");
        timerLabel.setEnabled(false);
        c.add(timerLabel);
        this.setSize(150,150);
        this.setVisible(true);
        int k = 100;
        while(true)
        {

            timerLabel.setText(k+" seconds left");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            k--;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimerTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Container c = this.getContentPane(); // has border layout by DEFAULT
c.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // but now it has flow layout!
// ..
c.add(timerLabel);
```

So change that to:

```
Container c = this.getContentPane(); // has border layout by DEFAULT
// ..
c.add(timerLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); // PAGE_START is AKA 'NORTH'
```

### Other tips:

1. Don't extend `JFrame`, just use an instance of one.
2. `JButton timerLabel` is a confusing name, it should be `JButton timerButton`
3. `this.setTitle("Timer Test");` could be written `super("Timer Test");` or if using a standard (not extended) frame .. `JFrame frame = new JFrame("Timer Test");`
4. `this.setSize(150,150);` That size is just a guess. It would better be `this.pack();`
5. `while(true) .. Thread.sleep(1000);` Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.
6. `public static void main(String[] args) { new TimerTest(); }` Swing & AWT based GUIs should be created & updated on the EDT.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way could you please please take a loot at my other question as well? I'm stuck with JTextField...

Comment: *"Thanks a lot."* You're welcome. *"could you please please take a loot at my other question ..?"* camickr has suggested posting an MRE twice now. Like seen in this question. Let me know when the other question has one. It's rare I'll look at code snippets and at the moment I'm too busy.